# How do you run code for the duration of a sound file? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently making an app that plays instructions for an exercise and tracks you.

Anyway, one of the things I want for the app is it tracks you for the duration of the sound file, then moves onto another screen.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a callback function from the audio framework, which you probably can use. It's called when the audio stops playing. In your case that might be when your sound file is done.

```
 func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    
       print( "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying() just started, successfully flag == \(flag)")
        
       // ...

 }
```